# A (possibly T1) topological space has a dense subset which is homeomorphic to the whole space. What can be said about the space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a (possibly T1, that is, singleton subsets are closed) topological space. Suppose that there is a *proper* subset $D \subset X$ such that:

- $D$ is dense in $X$;
- $D$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

What can be said about $X$?

Comment: A reasonable condition here would be that $X$ is also compact. Note that this means that $X$ is *not* a compactification of $D$ since $D$ is already compact. What I'm looking for here is what additional properties these conditions force $X$ to have: for example, do the conditions mean that $X$ has to be Hausdorff? (My initial guess is probably not.) I'm wondering whether the conditions severely limit the types of space that $X$ can be or if it leaves the possibilities much more open.

Comment: Also posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209391/a-compact-t1-topological-space-has-a-proper-dense-subset-to-which-it-is-homeomor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is awfully broad; it’s not clear that much of interest can be said. For what they’re worth, here are a few simple observations and examples.

The most obvious consequence is that $X$ must be infinite. We can also see right away that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then it cannot be compact: a proper subset homeomorphic to $X$ would be compact, and since $X$ is Hausdorff it would be closed and therefore not dense in $X$. On the other hand, any infinite space with the cofinite topology is a compact $T_1$ example.

The first Hausdorff example that comes to mind is $\Bbb Q$. A less obvious example is $X=C\setminus\{1\}$, where $C$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set. $X$ is well-known to be homeomorphic to $\Bbb N\times C$, where $\Bbb N$ has the discrete topology, which has the proper dense subset $\Bbb N\times X$. This in turn is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N\times(\Bbb N\times C)$ and hence to $\Bbb N\times C$ and thus to $X$.

All three of these examples are homogeneous, in the sense that if $x$ and $y$ are any points of the space, there is an autohomeomorphism of the space taking $x$ to $y$. However, there are non-homogeneous examples as well, since an arbitrary discrete union (topological sum) or Cartesian product of examples is also an example. Indeed, in both constructions it suffices that one of the summands or factors have the property; this immediately leads to a great variety of examples.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed and informative response, and those examples are extremely helpful.  
What they reveal is that I can stop worrying about whether I've missed something obvious and general about this problem. The spaces which I'm considering do have a specific topology on them, and since these examples have quite varied topologies, you've helped me see that an answer to the particular situation I'm examining isn't going to come from considering so general a set of conditions as those I provided in the question.  
Thank you again.

Comment: @Christian: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid too many comments, I'll convert them into an answer.

First of all, there are many examples of such spaces:

1. The positive rationals $\mathbb Q^+$ are an example. Let $f:\mathbb Q^+\to\mathbb Q^+$ be defined by $f(q)=q^2$. This is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb Q^+$ to $f(\mathbb Q^+)$ and $f(\mathbb Q^+)$ is dense in $\mathbb Q^+$ but $2\notin f(\mathbb Q^+)$.
2. For $n\geq 2$, $\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to its dense subset $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}^{n−1}\times[0,\infty)$.
3. Infinite-dimensional Banach spaces also seem like good candidates.

Such spaces are not necessarily Hausdorff. Take any infinite set $X$ and equip it with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$. Then any injective map $f:X\to X$ onto a proper subset of $X$ is a homeomorphism onto a dense subset of $X$.

A compact Hausdorff space satisfying your conditions does not exist: $D$ would have to be closed in $X$ and therefore not dense.

This still leaves some room for compact $T_1$ spaces possibly satisfying your conditions. Indeed, $\mathbb Z$ equipped with the cofinite topology is such a space. It is compact and $T_1$ and homeomorphic to $2\mathbb Z$, which is dense in $\mathbb Z$, since it is infinite.

If I come up with more ideas, I'll post them here.

Comment: Thank you for the examples. Like the answer above, they've really helped clarify my understanding of what's going on here, and that any answer I can hope to get is going to come from consideration of the specific topology I'm looking at rather than such a general case as this. 

It's just a relief to know that working further on the more general situation won't be of more help here. The examples were definitely useful, and thanks again.

(Oh, one question—is it typical to thank the poster of an answer on this site? I'm new to this site and I wouldn't want to come across as being over-the-top.)

Comment: @ChristianHoffland: Glad to help. I don't think a consensus has been reached regarding thanking the poster (see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/what-is-the-etiquette-about-leaving-short-thank-you-comments?lq=1) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17558/is-it-inappropriate-to-post-a-thank-you-as-a-comment)), but I'm pretty sure nobody will be offended if you decide to do so.